# Installing 32 and 64-bit Oracle client but 32-bit installer crashes

Tags: 32bit-64bit, oracle12c, oracleclient

I am trying to install Oracle 12c instant 32-bit client alongside my 64-bit installation because I can't connect Visual Studio to the 64-bit version (throws *BadImageFormatException*). I run the installer and give it another directory for home, so it's like this:

64-bit: `D:\app\MyUser\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1` (previously installed)

32-bit: `D:\app\Lazar\product\12.1.0\dbhome_x84`

The installer performs the checks and sends me to next step. I click *install* and it crashes!

Can someone please help?

Comment: just thoughts... Would it be worth installing one of them (32 bit version) in a virtual pc initially? That way you can use both versions without them confusing each other? data can be shared between them.

Comment: @RyanVincent The problem is I have a due date on a faculty project and don't have the time to install Oracle, .NET and Visual Studio all over again. Would you recommend where to learn more on how to use Oracle installed on VM from standard OS?

Comment: maybe interesting? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html

Comment: What 'installer' are you running for the instant client? You can just unzip [the distributed files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html)?

Comment: @RyanVincent I already have Virtaual Box, I just don't know how to use it as a service for my DB client :)

Comment: @AlexPoole I wasn't aware that was an option. Thanks! Could you please tell me if I'm correct when I say that, for a .NET application, I need to download and unzip both *basic* and *ODBC* versions in the same folder?

Comment: I have no idea if .NET supports the instant client, but I don't see why not. You unzip whatever packages you need into the same folder though, yes. I mentioned instant client because the first line of your question does: Are you really trying to install two versions of the full client? Or the full 32-bit client alongside a full 64-bit server? Either way the logs should give you some idea why it crashed.

Comment: @AlexPoole Well, that is what was suggested in other threads here - two clients with symbolic links... I'll see how to wiggle my way out of this one :) Thank you for your comments, as insightful as ever!

Answer (score 20):

I've actually run into the same problem. It looks like it is some sort of issue with the registry.

It appears to be a missing registry entry for the location of the Oracle Inventory. The below blog explains the following steps to add the missing registry key:

1. Open regedit
2. Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node
3. Create a new key with name "Oracle"
4. Go to Oracle and then create a new String Value with name "inst_loc"
5. Give the value as "C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\Inventory"
6. Retry installation

This blog post has more detail on the fix (though not much) and is where I originally found my solution.

https://oracledba1949.wordpress.com/2016/03/11/oracle-12-1-0-2-32bit-client-installation-on-windows-2012-x64bit/

Comment: This fixed my issue completely. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue and finally realized that Oracle installer doesn't support both 64bit and 32bit versions alongside. At least as you have mentioned in the question, it has got a bug. Here how I resolved the problem.

1. Hence both 64bit & 32bit versions unable to install alongside, first, uninstall the 64bit version.

   - Run the command %ORACLE_HOME%\deinstall\deinstall.bat
   - If any errors occur while uninstall, refer to the log and correct accordingly.
2. Recommend to restart the computer.
3. Install the 32bit version.

This will resolve your problem.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, however, since many of us are forced to support different applications, some running 32-bit oracle and other running 64-bit. I've had no issues installing 64-bit after 32-bit in the past, but running 32-bit install after 64-bit seems to be an issue.

Comment: @Grungondola, Were you able to run 64-bit installer after running 32-bit?

Comment: yes. I was able to resolve this using Andrew Hale's solution. It worked perfectly, and now both are installed and running just fine on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! The Andrew Hale's solution worked for me on Windows Server 2019. I was exactly in the same situation as dzenesiz.

Remember to check if the key exists before create it. You can use:

```
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ORACLE /v inst_loc
```